# picklist and opportunity name should be refelected in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

User when clicks "Survey" button in opportunity page, VF page should be displayed with questions(consider a picklist field) from a custom object and when user answers the question(the answer field is an input field) and clicks submit button the answers and the opportunity name should be stored in the same  custom object.

**status:**
i have tried doing with my code it is not showing any error and instead of ooportunity name opportunity id is displaying and picklist field is not reflecting

my code is

**controller:**

```
public class picklist { 
    public opportunity opp{get;set;}

      public  sampletest__c sampletest {get;set;}


    public List<SelectOption> securityOptions {get;set;}
    public picklist(ApexPages.StandardController opportunity){


        securityOptions = new List<SelectOption>();


Schema.DescribeFieldResult securityFieldDescription = sampletest__c.Security_Question__c.getDescribe();

for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry: securityFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){

securityOptions.add(new SelectOption( pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));


if (picklistEntry.defaultValue){
sampletest.Security_Question__c = pickListEntry.getValue();
} 
} 
}
    public void sampletest(){
      sampletest=new sampletest__c();
      opp=new Opportunity();
sampletest.Opportunity_name__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ;
string id=[select name from opportunity where name='suguna' LIMIT 1].name;

insert sampletest;

    }

}
```

[image: vf page]

can any one help me with my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sampletest.Opportunity_name__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ;`

In the above line, you are saving the Id to a `Opportunity_Name__c` which probably is a string field. What else are you expecting?

If you want to save the name, since you have the Opportunity already, just do

`sampletest.Opportunity_name__c = opp.Name`.

OR

change Opportunity_Name__c to a lookup/master-detail field and then your code will save the reference and you will see the name of the Opportunity.

*****Edit******

Modify constructor

```
public picklist(ApexPages.StandardController opportunity){

this.opp = (Opportunity)opportunity.getRecord(); 

..... //rest of your code

}
```

Comment: i already tried that oop.name but still i am unable to see name

Comment: sampletest.Opportunity_name__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ;instead of id i used name and tried that but the result is not reflecting

Comment: No. You can't get the name like that. Because it's not a page parameter.

Comment: also your opp is an empty opportunity. Instead in the Constructor just do this `this.opp = (Opportunity)opportunity.getRecord(); ` .

Comment: aslam i got it but using soql query i got it

Comment: i used like this string oppid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ;
sampletest.Opportunity_name__c=[select name from opportunity where id=:oppid LIMIT 1].name;

Comment: can u tell me how fetch picklist value to custom object record

Comment: why are you doing this `sampletest=new sampletest__c();` in sampletest method? Remove this from `sampletest` method and move it to the constructor.

Comment: ya i removed it in method and  placed it in constructor

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a related list to the Opportunity layout and using the New button to create new question/answer pairs that are related to the Opportunity.

The Sample Test object would have 3 fields:

1. Opportunity (Master-Detail)
2. Question (Picklist)
3. Answer (Text, Text Area, or Text Area Long)

When the user clicks 'New Sample Test', Salesforce automatically provides the exact page that you are requesting.

Comment: it is not like that when ever you are trying to create a record in opportunity you will get buttons ryt same we have to add a custom button called survey when ever it is clicked the same procedure should follow

Comment: by creating a new custom button and providing link we can do that.instead of using releated lists by using vf cant we do that?